# Test that score isn't predicted by chance

Tags: machine-learning, probability, hypothesis-testing

I have developed machine learning machinery to predict links in an undirected network. For each link I calculated corresponding score which reflect the probability that the  link occurs in the network. For example, the dataset looks like:

```
1 2 0.43
1 3 0.98
2 4 0.05
3 6 0.02
```

First two numbers designate nodes of the networks and the last number is the prediction score. The prediction score is calculated as Jaccard coefficient which computes the ratio of common neighbors out of all neighbors. Two nodes, $u$ and $v$, are more likely to have a link if they have many common neighbors relative to the total number of neighbors they have. Jaccard index is defined as:
$$
s(u,v) = \frac{\vert \Gamma(u) \cap \Gamma (v) \vert}{\vert \Gamma(u) \cup \Gamma (v) \vert}
$$
where $\Gamma(\cdot)$ denote number of neighbors.

**Question:** How can I assess the predictive value of particular score? How can I know that the value 0.98 between nodes 1 and 3 isn't just predicted by chance. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to give more infromation if you want us to help. How is the score evaluated ? would be a good start

Comment: @RUser4512 thanks. I explain how the score is evaluated.

Comment: In a most basic approach you simply need some kind of zero hypothesis, i.e., a way to make a random (yet representative wrt your real networks) graph in which adding any more edge would be an error. Then just apply your method to many such graphs and gather the distribution of score expected by chance.